# Any example of using 2 different classes for onProgressUpdate in Asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've been looking all over the place for this, and the only answer I've had was "use Pair", but I can't get this to work either.

Here's what I need to:
In Asynctask I need to update both a progress bar, and text. Because of this my Asynctask generic cannot be just Integer and not just String, but both. This is so I can have both classes within the "onProgressUpdate" method.

Can somebody give me some example or links as to how I add the strings and increase the integer in "doInBackground", and how to implement this in the "onProgressUpdate"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create your own simple class to hold the variables and then pass that?

Or, what if you pass a string that you can parse and get the values you need?  If you take your first string += ":" + int, then make use of something like

```
String myString = passedString.substring(0, passedString.lastIndexOf(":")))
int i = Integer.parseInt(passedString.substring(passedString.lastIndexOf(":")+1));
```

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the only way to do it.
I just wanted to know if there another way to pass both values without having to create a custom class...

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question; there are mainly two things which you want to do:

1) Handle a UI thread while in the doIneBackground().
2) Implement the onProgressUpdate().

Basically we shouldn't try to access the UI thread while a background process is running.
The reason for that is very clear... @ OS level there will be so many thread will be running.And in that case It will be chaos on the screen, if we can update UI from background thread.

For the 2nd one I would like recommend you to take a look at this example:

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(YourActivity.this);
downloadTask.execute("the url to the file you want to download");
mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        downloadTask.cancel(true);
    }
});
```

In the AsynTask:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

private Context context;

public DownloadTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user 
    // presses the power button during download
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
         getClass().getName());
    wl.acquire();

    try {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report 
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                 return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() 
                     + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled())
                    return null;
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ignored) { }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
    } finally {
        wl.release();
    }
    return null;
}}
```

The method above (doInBackground) runs always on a background thread. You shouldn't do any UI tasks there. On the other hand, the onProgressUpdate and onPreExecute run on the UI thread, so there you can change the progress bar:

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    if (result != null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Regards

Sathya

Comment: Thanx, but my only question was how to pass 2 types to onProgressUpdate.
Your answer shows how the whole asynctask workflow goes, but only passes 1 type to onProgressUpdate which is not what I was looking for.

Thanx anyways though.